# Wordpress & jQuery event handler with .on()

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-events

I have some trouble with jQuery`s` .on()`/`.bind()` function.
What I am trying to do is attach a click-event to a certain element, so whenever it is used in the content, it can be clicked and a popup opens, without the need to declare a function individually.

This is my code: It worked for simple testing, but not within a local Wordpress environment. No click-event gets attached, debug didn't tell me anything... :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#eins_audiotrigger').bind('click', function() {
    if($('#eins_audiotarget').attr('class') != 'fadeInUp'){
        $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeInUp');
    }
    else {
        $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeOutDown');   
    }
});
    
});
```

All right, here is a few more details:

I used this to include jQuery: [include jQuery into wordpress](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way)

I tried everything regarding the no-conflict mode of jQuery. I also have another (document).ready function that gets called and works fine (is there a problem with multiple (document).ready in one file?

With this whole thing i want to call a simple css-animation, that is defined in the class I want to add to the element. Basically a will fly in and there is a media-player embedded.

This works when called straight out of the post, but not if this event should be added to the respective button in advance, which should be realized because Wordpress strips out the script-tags when the normal editor is used.

Comment: When you say "Debug didn't tell me anything" you mean no errors in the console?

Comment: yeah, no error in the console

Comment: Can you `console.log($)` and post the result?

Comment: "..so whenever it is used..." -> use a class instead of an ID if you use the element multiple times. Make sure jquery is correctly included locally. You gotta care cause you remove classes in your code and you might want to specify is better.. Maybe you should tell us what your click function should be doing?

Comment: @gulty, using the **same** element multiple times is no reason for a class. It is still one unique element

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its a problem with $ so try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#eins_audiotrigger').bind('click', function() {
        if($('#eins_audiotarget').hasClass('fadeInUp') === false){
            $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeInUp');
        }
        else {
            $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeOutDown');   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: didn´t help. jQuery is working when called inside the page and is included correct (think so). 
one concole.log($) the reply is as follows:  
function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 }

Comment: check this link http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with it! As a Javascript-newbee i realized, that i can simply add a click to the button by doing this:

```
    $('#trigger').click( function() {
        $('#trigger').removeClass().addClass('fadeOutDown');
        $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeInUp');
});
$('#closeIt').click( function () {
        $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeOutDown');
        $('#trigger').removeClass().addClass('fadeInUp');
        setTimeout( function() {$('#trigger').removeClass()}, 1000);
});
```

So many things to learn here!
Thanks for support!